# Bert return nan as lost

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, bert-language-model, nlp-question-answering

I am trying to make an model that is trained on custom data to eventually make a chatbot from it. The problem is training the model resolves in loss as nan.

I am trying to to train the model and see some sort of loss but this loop breaks and does not train the model. I want to get an answer from the model but it returns nothing

this is the code:

```
# Preprocess your dataset
questions = ["What is the capital of France", "Who invented the telephone"]
answers = ["Paris", "Alexander Graham Bell"]

encoded_inputs = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(
    list(zip(questions, answers)),
    padding=True,
    truncation=True,
    max_length=256,
    return_tensors='pt'
)

# Fine-tune the BERT model
optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=1e-6)

input_ids = encoded_inputs['input_ids']
attention_mask = encoded_inputs['attention_mask']
start_positions = torch.tensor([tokenizer.encode(answer, add_special_tokens=False)[0] for answer in answers])
end_positions = torch.tensor([tokenizer.encode(answer, add_special_tokens=False)[-1] for answer in answers])

model.train()
for epoch in range(5):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    outputs = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, start_positions=start_positions, end_positions=end_positions)
    loss = outputs.loss
    
    # Check for NaN loss
    if torch.isnan(loss):
        print(f"NaN loss encountered at epoch {epoch+1}. Training stopped.")
        break
    
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1} Loss: {loss.item()}")

    # Check for loss explosion
    if loss.item() > 1e5:
        print(f"Loss exploded at epoch {epoch+1}. Training stopped.")
        break

# Test the model on the training questions
test_question = "What is the capital of France?"

encoded_test = tokenizer(test_question, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors='pt')
test_input_ids = encoded_test['input_ids']
test_attention_mask = encoded_test['attention_mask']

model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    outputs = model(test_input_ids, attention_mask=test_attention_mask)
    start_scores = outputs.start_logits
    end_scores = outputs.end_logits

    # Get the predicted start and end indices
    predicted_start = torch.argmax(start_scores)
    predicted_end = torch.argmax(end_scores)

    # Decode the predicted answer
    predicted_answer = tokenizer.decode(test_input_ids[0][predicted_start:predicted_end+1])

print(f"Predicted Answer: {predicted_answer}")
```

Comment: Can you run it again with `torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)`? If there's an issue with the gradient, it should tell you

Comment: I have tried it but this does not seem to work I am just trying to make an model that is trained on questions and returns an answer. I do not now if this is the way to go do you have any ideas